# MySql simple Subqueries / Join

Tags: mysql, database

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * From `users` AS `User`
LEFT JOIN `picks` AS `Pick` ON (`Pick`.`User_id` = `User`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN  `owners` AS `owner` ON (`owner`.`id` = `Pick`.`owner_id`)
LEFT JOIN  `owners_seeds` AS `OwnersSeed` ON (`OwnersSeed`.`ownerdate` = (`owner`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN  `labels` AS `Label` ON (`Label`.`id` = `Pick`.`label_id`) WHERE User.market_id = 1111
```

The query works fine but the results goes like this :

```
USER X

PICK X

OWNER X
```

etc..

Since every user has many pick but each pick has only one owner and so on, I would like to have my results be printed like :

> USER X
>
> 1. PICK 1
>
>    1. Owner 1
>
>       1. Owner seed
>    2. Owner 2
>
>       1. Owner seed
>    3. Owner 3...
> 2. Pick 2

etc

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    users.user,
    picks.pick,
    owners.owner,
    owners_seeds.seed
From
    `users`
    LEFT JOIN `picks` ON (`Picks`.`User_id` = `Users`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN  `owners` ON (`owners`.`id` = `Picks`.`owner_id`)
    LEFT JOIN  `owners_seeds` ON (`Owners_Seeds`.`ownerdate` = (`owners`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN  `labels` ON (`Labels`.`id` = `Picks`.`label_id`)
WHERE
    users.market_id = 1111
group by users.user, picks.pick, owners.owner, owners_seeds.seed
order by users.user, picks.pick, owners.owner, owners_seeds.seed;
```

If your schema is as you describe, this should output a result similar to:

```
user     pick     owner    seed
------------------------------------
1        1        x        a
1        2        y        b
1        3        z        c
2        1        x        a
. . .
```